# Migrating to Ionic 5 from Ionic 3 operator .then shows error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native, ionic5

Hello I am trying to migrate my project from Ionic 3 to Ionic 5.

I have a function for social sharing and the operator **.then()** is redlighted

> Property then does not exit on type void

this is a function

```
shareMedia()
{
  this.socialSharing.share(this.title, '', 'https://example.com/api/api/uploads/' + this.image_path, 'https://example.com')
    .then(()=>{
    }).catch(()=>{

    });
}
```

any help?

Comment: depends on what `this.socialSharing.share()` is

Comment: Can you elaborate Suraj? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/social-sharing

Comment: which version of ionic native plugin are you using and how did you import it?

Comment: "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.27.0", via npm i

Comment: and your import statement?

Comment: import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing'; constructor(private socialSharing: SocialSharing,)

Comment: Import is changed to: `import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing/ngx';`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tomas for future consideration

Change

```
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing';
```

To

```
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing/ngx';
```